# php messing up on server 2012 running iis8

Tags: php, windows-server-2012, iis-8

We are in the process of migrating our sites from a windows server 2003 to a new windows server 2012 running ii8, however the we have the following issues

1. any characters such as ç or ñ show up as ? marks
2. the first site runs ok but any other sites throw up an error when connecting to the 2012 mssql server (Uncaught exception 'ADODB_Exception' with message 'odbc_mssql error: [S1000: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Connection is busy with results for another hstmt])

initially I thought it was the sql server but I have managed to connect the old sites running on server 2003 iis6 to the new sql server and they all run fine.

I then installed some older versions of php, 5.216, 5.3.28, 5.4.24, 5.5.8 all with exactly the same results

So I think the issue has to be with the new server, and something maybe to do with fast cgi or some configuration on it.

I've tried researching it and it seems that iis 7.5 had issues and did have a fix from MS but the fix is supposed to be included in server 2012 ii8 by default and you cant install it anyway.

Has anyone got any idea or can any one give me any clues?

thanks

Comment: Are you using UTF-8 in the database encoding?

Comment: Maybe the problems come from your backed up database. Try restore to another database, with utf-8 or others encoding, and query some data from SQL Studio.

Comment: Like I have said I have connected the current site on the 2003 server to the 2012 DB and they all work fine, and displaying all characters correctly